# data() method is not working in jquery 1.9?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i have code that uses jquery 1.4

```
           if (td.data().appointments === undefined)
            td.data().appointments = [event];
        else td.data().appointments.push(event);
```

i want to update jquery to 1.9 but data() method is not workig in 1.9 ,

if i replace data with attr then push (appointments.push(event)) is not working

Any alternative to fix this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `appointments` in parameter as a key to [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of using it like property,

*Syntax* `.data( key )`

```
if (td.data("appointments") === undefined)
```